# HTML: border not visible in <td> tag in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a simple table in HTML> I want each cell in the the table to have its own border. I defined a CSS property for it like:

```
td {
    width: 350px;   
    height: 50px;
    border:thick;
    border-color: black;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Html:

```
< table border="0">
    <tr><td>Row1</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>Row2</td></tr>   
    <tr><td>Row3</td></tr>
</table>
```

The border is visible in the "Dreamweaver Design Mode" but when the document runs in firefox, the border vanishes. Why is it happening?

Comment: Remove the space between `<` and `table` that is invalid in HTML

Comment: No, still doesnt work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:-

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nesu9/)

#### [See Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border)

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Row1</td></tr> 
    <tr><td>Row2</td></tr>   
    <tr><td>Row3</td></tr>
</table>


td{
width: 350px;   
height: 50px;
border: thick solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: @NavneetSaini Please mark as answer if you think this is the answer that you are looking for...

Comment: The relevant part here is `border: thick solid black`, because it sets `border-style: solid`. Without it, or something similar, the `border-style` property has its initial value `none`, so no border appears, no matter what you set for the other properties.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like this, where you get deviation between browsers, I always recommend going directly to a validator!

http://validator.nu/

Gives me these errors when I put your code in (with the css in a style tag in the head):

```
Error: Bad character   after <. Probable cause: Unescaped <. Try escaping it as &lt;. At line 15, column 2 tyle>↩</head>↩< table border=" Error: Stray start tag tr. From line 16, column 5; to line 16, column 8
="0">↩    <tr><td>Ro Error: Stray start tag td. From line 16, column 9; to line 16, column 12
>↩    <tr><td>Row1</ Error: Stray end tag td. From line 16, column 17; to line 16, column 21 r><td>Row1</td></tr>  Error: Stray end tag tr. From line 16, column 22; to line 16, column 26
>Row1</td></tr> ↩     Error: Stray start tag tr. From line 17, column 5; to line 17, column 8 /tr> ↩    <tr><td>Ro Error: Stray start tag td. From line 17, column 9; to line 17, column 12  ↩    <tr><td>Row2</ Error: Stray end tag td. From line 17, column 17; to line 17, column 21 r><td>Row2</td></tr>  Error: Stray end tag tr. From line 17, column 22; to line 17, column 26
>Row2</td></tr>   ↩   Error: Stray start tag tr. From line 18, column 5; to line 18, column 8 r>   ↩    <tr><td>Ro Error: Stray start tag td. From line 18, column 9; to line 18, column 12  ↩    <tr><td>Row3</ Error: Stray end tag td. From line 18, column 17; to line 18, column 21 r><td>Row3</td></tr>↩ Error: Stray end tag tr. From line 18, column 22; to line 18, column 26
>Row3</td></tr>↩</tab Error: Stray end tag table. From line 19, column 1; to line 19, column 8 /td></tr>↩</table>
```

The most important being the firstish entry:

```
Error: Bad character   after <. Probable cause: Unescaped <. Try escaping it as &lt;. At line 15, column 2 tyle>↩</head>↩< table border=" Error: Stray start tag tr. From line 16, column 5; to line 16, column 8
```